# Image measure of a measure “multiplied” by the identity function

Tags: measure-theory

Let F be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. And let u be an F integrable function. Consider the integral:

$$\int u(a)aF(da)$$

Now consider a Borel measure $\mu$

\begin{equation}
\mu(B) = \int \mathbb{1}_{B}(u(a))a F(da) \qquad (\star)
\end{equation}

Where B is a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$.

How can we show that $\int u(a)aF(da)= \int a \mu(da)$? If this is true? I feel intuitively only that the equality is correct, but have not been able to show analytically.

This is my attempt to show the result, assuming F has a density f. We have

$$\int u(a)a F(da) = \int u(a) af(da)da$$

let $\phi(a)=af(a)$ and note

$$ \int u(a)a F(da) = \int u(a) \phi(a)da = \int u(a) \Phi(da)$$

where $\Phi$ is the measure given by $\Phi(B) = \int \mathbb{1}_{B}(a)aF(da)$. Now letting $\mu = \Phi\circ u^{-1}$ denote the image measure of $\Phi$ under $u$, we have

$$ \int u(a)a F(da) = \int a \Phi\circ u^{-1}(da) = \int a \mu(da)$$

We just need to confirm $(\star)$ is met. We have

$$
\mu(B) = \Phi\{\omega \vert u(\omega) \in B\} = \int \mathbb{1}_{\{\omega \vert u(\omega) \in B\}}(a)aF(da) = \int \mathbb{1}_{B}(u(a))aF(da) $$

I would appreciate any help to extend the argument, if correct, to general measures! WIthout  the density assumption.

Comment: You can just put $\mu(A)=\int u(a)aF(da)$ when $1\in A$ and $\mu(A)=0$ when $1\notin A$. Then $\int a\mu(da)=\int_{\{1\}}a\mu(da)=1\mu(\{1\})=\int u(a)aF(da)$.

Comment: Do you really want this factor $\mathbf{a}$ in $\int u(a)\mathbf{a}F(da)=\int \mathbf{a}\mu(da)$ to be just $a$ or to be any measurable function? For the problem as stated there are so many trivial choices of $\mu$ like the one above.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You are right. I have re-framed the question.

Comment: Is there perhaps a relation to the [change of variable formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537686) in probability?